# Reading a log/csv file and store each value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, parsing

I have a csv file with headers in first line and its values in all limes.

Headers be like :
header1,header2,header3,....

If there are total 200 lines i will get 199 header1, header2 values.

Am trying to store all the values of each header in an array.

The code i tried,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $logFile ); $i ++) {
                $rr = explode ( ',', $logFile [$i] );
                $eachline [] = $rr;
            }
```

when doing this am getting 200 arrays for each line.

If suppose there are seven headers, i need seven arrays with 199 elements in it.

By the by, I don't need all the header values, I need only some headers, i can take them by splitting first line and taking split[2], split[5]... Now I want to store every line's 2nd element, 5th element .. in an array.

Comment: have you tried `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: Like Rusland writes you should consider using existing code to read a csv. There can be issues where it's not enough to separate by comma. What about records where the comma is part of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want this. hope it helps.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $logFile ); $i ++) {
  $rr = explode ( ',', $logFile [$i] );
  foreach($rr as $key => $value)
  {
    $eachline[$key][] = $value;
  }
}
```

then `$eachline` will save the arrays for header1, header2,